# jquery form results are not showing. Is my code wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, output

I am having difficulty with my form. On one of my pages is a form. You enter info, click submit, and it returns with some result. Well, it is supposed to return with a result. It appears to do nothing, currently. However, if I check the header responses in my developer tools, it does show the results. So I know they are being called correctly, they just are not appearing on the webpage.

Here is the calling code:

```
    $content .= '
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
        $j(window).load(function(){
            $j("#pubverify-form").submit(function() {
                var str = $j(this).serialize();
                   $j.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "' . $cs_base_dir . 'verify.php",
                   data: str,
                   success: function(msg){
                        $j("#note").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                        {
                            $j(this).html(msg);
                        });
                    }
                 });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>';
```

Here is the code that I believe should show the results:

```
        $content .= '<div id="verify-a-rec" class="clear">';
        $content .= '<div id="fields">';
        $content .= '<h4>Verify A Recommendation</h4>';
        $content .= '<div class="verify_search">';
            $content .= '<form id="pubverify-form" action="">';
                    $content .= '<div class="label_wrap_verify"><label class="error" for="search_last_name">Last Name </label>';
                    $content .= '<div class="input_wrap_verify"><input name="search_last_name" type="text" id="search_last_name"/></div></div>'; 
                    $content .= '<div class="label_wrap_verify"><label class="error" for="search_dob">Birthdate (mm-dd-yyyy) </label>';
                    $content .= '<div class="input_wrap_verify"><input name="search_dob" type="text" id="search_dob"/></div></div>'; 
                    $content .= '<div class="label_wrap_verify"><label class="error" for="search_issue_date">Issue Date (mm-dd-yyyy)</label>';
                    $content .= '<div class="input_wrap_verify"><input name="search_issue_date" type="text" id="search_issue_date"/></div></div>'; 
                $content .= '<div class="button_wrap"><input type="submit" value="Verify" class="button" id="pubverify-submit" /></div>';
            $content .= '</form>';
        $content .= '</div>';
        $content .= '</div>';
        $content .= '<div style="clear:both"></div>';
        $content .= '<div id="note">';
        $content .= '<p>Enter a Recommendation ID and click Verify!</p>';
            $content .= '<div class="patient_wrapper">';
                $content .= '<div class="results_label">First Name </div>';
                $content .= '<div class="results_label">Last Name </div>';
                $content .= '<div class="results_label">Date of Birth </div>';
                $content .= '<div class="results_label">Issue Date </div>';
                $content .= '<div class="results_label">Expiration Date </div>';
                $content .= '<div class="results_label">Dr. Information </div>';
            $content .= '</div>';
        $content .= '</div>';
    $content .= '</div>';
return $content;
```

Can someone please help!?

Comment: You really should not mangle PHP, JavaScript and HTML together like this. Nightmares are made out of such code.

Comment: Either put the HTML in a HEREDOC, or remove the PHP tags and emit it as regular HTML.  The results will be MUCH cleaner.  Beyond that, check the JS console for any error messages.

Comment: @k0pernikus, It HAS been a nightmare. I didn't create the code, I have been the one that gets to go in and fix all of this crap. Any suggestions on cleaning up the code?

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher, There is no JS error messages on my Console currently.

Comment: If you want to maintain current version, then have your JS in its own file, have your template in its own file. Turn it into a MVC structure if you can. If your JS needs variable from the server, either print them in data-tags, expose JSON/objects in the template, or have your JS request the needed information separately on the fly. But I wonder if writing something new from scratch wouldn't be the faster thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part is wrong.

```
$j("#note").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
{
    $j(this).html(msg);
});
```

You need to remove the ajaxComplete code.

```
$j.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "' . $cs_base_dir . 'verify.php",
   data: str,
   success: function(msg){
       $j("#note").html(msg);
    }
 });
```

Comment: Totally worked! You are my hero! Stupid ajaxComplete. Is it not needed because of Jquery 1.9? I thought it was needed because the action is used and completed. Thus needing to show the msg after the ajax is completed. It worked previously, but I think my site updated Jquery, and the plugin is hard written using v1.6. Thanks again!

Comment: @420DankStank: No, not because of 1.9. The `success:` callback function is all you need in any version. The `$.ajaxComplete` is to assign a more generic function that is invoked any time *any* `$.ajax` request completes. You do that outside of any other request.

Comment: I see. Thank you. You have eased my two days worth of headache.